# MS Visual Studio regional settings, numbers

Tags: visual-studio, localization, formatting

I have been searching the Internet for a solution but not found one, hopefully someone here can help me?

The thing is, I am using MS Visual Studio 2008 and the regional setting is English (United States)

Example, using 1 million: 1,000,000.00

What I need to change this to is European standard, that is 1 million: 1.000.000,00

Perhaps a possibility to change the string format from the US: #,0;(#,0) to the European standard (which I have not found yet)??

Or does anybody have a better solution?

I am using Reporting Services

--EDIT--

```
MY ANSWER:
```

OK, for SSRS this is what I did.

Reports -> Properties -> Localization -> Language: es-ES 
[image]

Now my 1 million looks like this:

1.000.000,00

Comment: Do you mean that you MUST output 'european' number format no matter what the user regional settings are? Or you want to make sure you use the current format according to user regional settings?

Comment: Yes, no matter what the regional settings are on the PC. 
The option to set the number format to "European" or "US" depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using NumberFormatInfo (System.Globalization):

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
decimal d = 1000000M;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("n", nfi));
```

For applying these settings to the whole application add this code at the beginning (e.g. in the main() method):

```
CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
ci.NumberFormat = nfi;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
```

Comment: Whereever you want to display a number with this format...
Or if you want to change it for the whole application, you can do that with: 
    CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    ci.NumberFormat = nfi;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;